# Is it possible for there to be a black hole with the mass of an atom?

Tags: black-holes, mass

Is it possible for there to be a black hole with the mass of, say, a hydrogen atom? I heard that it is not, because the mass would have to be concentrated in less than a Planck volume, which is impossible. What is the minimum possible mass of a black hole, anyway, if there is indeed a minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum black hole mass is called the Planck Mass, and it is the mass of a black hole with a radius equal to the Planck length. You can derive it using the Schwarzschild Radius formula:

$r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$

Setting $r_s$ equal to the Planck length $l_p$:

$l_p=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$

$\frac{l_p{c^2}}{2G}=M$

This value is the Planck mass and the minimum mass a black hole can be.

Comment: On what basis do you claim that a black hole cannot have a radius less than the Planck length or a mass less than the Planck mass? I realize that there are some speculative theories of quantum gravity in which this is the case, but they are just that, speculative. There is as yet no generally accepted theory of quantum gravity, and so the answer should be "we don't know".

Comment: It’s on the basis that our current understanding of physics breaks down at the Planck scale. There can be smaller masses, but our current understanding of physics holds until we reach the Planck length. However, as you pointed out, we don’t actually know. The answer that I shared is what we can guess with our theories now.

Comment: We don't even know that the theories break down at the Planck scale... there are reasons to think they do, but it's entirely possible that general relativity holds at all scales. There's definitely no evidence that spacetime is discrete, and some good (but not conclusive) evidence that it is continuous.

Comment: @user107952 looking back at my Planck mass equation I’m not sure the value is exactly that, but the idea is that (with our current model) a black hole does have a “minimum mass.” Of course, quantum gravity makes the nature of it uncertain (we don’t have a TOE), so we can’t be 100% sure yet if there is one.